# 403 Display with WWW [Nginx]

Tags: nginx, web, http-status-code-404

My access to the site is only possible with this domain name:

```
https://example.com [Working]
```

That's I can access it **but** if I add `www`; I get the 403 screen.

*This is my Nginx conf. file:*

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     domain.com;
    rewrite_log     on;

    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1&cmd=$2 last; 
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 last; 
        }
    }


    location ~* \.php$ { 
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index                   index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }


}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Both the DNS (A-)records for your domain AND your subdomain point to the same IP-address?

Comment: I'm not talking about subdomain. I can't accessing the site with `www` @paolo

Comment: Well, you say "if I add www". But where do you "add" www, if not in the domain (`https://www.example.com`)? Keep in mind that `www.example.com` in fact _is_ a subdomain of `example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Actually, the answer is very simple.

`server_name     domain.com;` **to** `server_name     domain.com www.domain.com;`

So I'm going to fix the problem.